# getting this error in server at the time of word to pdf converting, in locall working good but after uploading on iis 8.5 giving this error

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm getting this error in server at the time of word to pdf converting, in locall working good but after uploading on iis 8.5:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word,
>   Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: check your publish folder on the server, is there a file named "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll"?

Comment: yes its already in folder

Comment: already installed office 2007 in server and also checked Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in server publish folder but still getting same error

Comment: @JanakJangir have you really bought a Word 2007 license for every user of your site? Because that's what you need to do if you want to call Word from a web site. It doesn't scale at all either, every request will end up starting a new Word instance, quickly taking up all of the server's RAM

Comment: @JanakJangir as for the error, it does mean that the file can't be found. Perhaps the dll in the server folder has a different version from the one the application expects. Or the installed Word version added a different DLL version in the GAC

Answer (score 0):

"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" this dll is missing on the server that why this error is occurring so you can update this dll on server

Comment: thanks for your feedback, it is done with help of dinktopdf and its working fine :)